# Determining if a file exists on a network drive without a 20 second timeout

Tags: c++, windows, networking, boost

Is there an easy way to determine if a file on a remote system exists without a 20-25 second hang if it doesn't?

Functions like...

```
PathFileExists();
GetFileAttributes();
```

...don't allow you to set a timeout duration, so when the file doesn't exist you end up waiting for a long time. I think it might be possible to put one of these calls into a thread and set the thread to expire after 1 second (or whatever), but I'd prefer to use a lightweight native Windows function or boost function rather than an inelegant threading solution.

Comment: Any `boost` function would relay on some Windows API...

Comment: I'm sure it's true that many of them would. I just don't know boost well enough to know whether it contains a function that efficiently implements the threading workaround I mentioned (for example).

Comment: No. The only valid way to check whether any resource is available is to try to use it in the normal way. Any other technique is liable to timing-window problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to prove a negative, but I will argue that no such method exists.

The normal Windows asynchronous I/O method uses the `OVERLAPPED` structure, and in its documentation it references the `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` methods. From the other side, no variant of `GetFileAttributes` mentions `OVERLAPPED` or asynchronous I/O. Hence, it seems safe to assume it is always synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no, generally there’s no easy way.

If your server is configured to responds to pings, you can use `IcmpSendEcho` API to ping the server before accessing it’s shared files, the API’s quite simple and it accepts the timeout.

If your server doesn’t respond to pings (by default modern versions of Windows don’t), you can write a function that tries to connect to TCP port 135 or 445, if connected closes the connection and returns success, if failed returns error. This will allow you to implement shorter timeout than the default.

In both methods, you’ll need to resolve the network drive path into the name of the server, see e.g. `GetVolumePathName` API.